# Separating integrals

Tags: integration

I went across the following equality:

[image]

May I ask why does the first line equate to the second line? What is the proof behind that?

Note: $H$ are linear operators.  $T$ means that the linear operators are ordered such that operators with lower value of $t$ as their argument are placed on the right.

Comment: What is **T**? ${}$

Comment: @Sobi I will add this definition to the question

Comment: There are $n!$ different arrangements of the arguments.  See if you can work out what happens in the $n=2$ term.